# Запятая между прилагательными

Tags: запятые, прилагательные, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Нужна ли запятая между прилагательными в этом предложении: «Подобрать новую, интересную для вас игру.». И почему? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*Подобрать **новую, интересную** для вас игру.*

1. Запятая в данном случае ставится по формальному признаку: **определителительный оборот стоит после одночного определения.** Такое правило есть у Розенталя для причастного оборота, но оно справедливо и для оборота на основе прилагательного.

Согласованные определения являются однородными: 7) если за одиночным определением следует определение, выраженное причастным оборотом: малоизвестные, расположенные на отшибе курганы; чёрные, гладко причёсанные волосы. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

2. Но даже при отсутствии оборота отношения между прилагательными будут однородными: новая, интересная игра, так как раскрывают одну общую тему и определяют существительное независимо: новая игра, интересная игра.